# Difference between Ilog and TelemetryClient for logging details in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app

I am using Azure function app v3 and I want to log details into Application Insights.
There is by default ILogger in function app. what is the difference between `Ilogger` and `TelemetryClient` to log details into App Insights. which is the best way to log details?

Any response is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are certain things you cannot do using `ILogger`, like tracking [multi dimension metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/get-metric#multi-dimensional-metrics) or events. The `Ilogger` lets you only log to the exceptions and traces tables of App Insights. Also, using `ILogger` you cannot log extra properties to the custom dimensions field of the telemetry without having them in the message as well using [structured logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-message-template).

That said, I'd say that for Azure Functions you almost always can do what you want using the `ILogger` interface, but it is up to you to decide.

Comment: So if `ILogger` has a subset of the functionalities of `TelemetryClient`, when should we ever use `ILogger` in favor of `TelemetryClient`. The only reason I can think of is to log to different sinks (console/file etc.) than application insights?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck well, I suppose when you don't want to have a too tight coupling with Application Insights it can make sense. For the future I am betting on Open Telemetry with an Application Insights exporter so I can keep things seperated.